# Proxy server using sockets .net

Tags: c#, sockets, proxy

I'm writing a proxy server and using it for sockets. The problem is how to detect the end of data and close socket, or understand how browser is doing it.

My proxy is very simple, it just forwards requests using certain network adapter to intranet proxy, so there is no request parsing and SSL do not require extra authentication.

```
public void Start(IPEndPoint local, IPEndPoint remote) {
    _mainSocket.Bind(local);
    _mainSocket.Listen(100);
    while (true) {
        var source = _mainSocket.Accept();
        var destination = new TcpForwarder();                
        var state = new State(source, destination._mainSocket, localSockets);
        destination._mainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.94.136.231"), 0));
        destination.Connect(remote, source);
        source.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, 0, OnDataReceive, state);
    }
}

private void Connect(EndPoint remoteEndpoint, Socket destination) {
    var state = new State(_mainSocket, destination, local, destinationstate);
    _mainSocket.Connect(remoteEndpoint);
    _mainSocket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnDataReceive, state);
}
```

OnDataReceive
just read everything send to another socket and continue listening

But for every request there is made another socket connection, and I don't know when I can close it, even if I close browser both sockets still have Connected status, and they stay forever, as this proxy is local I can restart everything when it fails but, still I want to understand how requests work, isn't TCP/IP request same as open socket and send certain headers?

Comment: TCP is the network transport layer while browser has an application layer using http above the TCP layer.  The method for determining EOM in http uses the tags.   Usually at msdn the socket class which TCP inherits have best documentation.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.begindisconnect(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like if i close socket if there was no data received then it's enough, browser receives everything it requires and there is no leak, so i assume it's correct way, it was strange that if i just get image file, then socket stays connected for some time

```
var bytesTransferred = state.SourceSocket.EndReceive(readSocket);
if (bytesTransferred == 0)
{
    state.SourceSocket.Close();
    state.DestinationSocket.Close();
}
```